# Is it possible to do something both "cleverly" and "unknowingly" at same time?

Tags: adverbs

I saw the sentence below in [a New York Times article](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/04/16/the-look-of-love-is-in-the-dogs-eyes/?action=click&contentCollection=Opinion&module=MostEmailed&version=Full&region=Marginalia&src=me&pgtype=article), and wonder -- is it possible?

> There is a possibility that **dogs cleverly and unknowingly utilized** a
>   natural system meant for bonding a parent with his or her child.

(To me, "cleverly" has always suggested "actively knowing what you're doing" -- so seeing it used with "unknowingly" strikes me as bizarre, and I wonder if I'm missing something about "cleverly.")

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible?

Comment: @GEdgar because to me, "cleverly" has always suggested "actively knowing what you're doing" -- so seeing it used with "unknowingly" strikes me as bizarre, and I wonder if I'm missing something about "cleverly."

Comment: Paste that comment into your question - then your question will be perfect :-)

Comment: @ShaneF. - I agree, it sounds dumb.  If it was so clever, how does the author assume the lack of knowledge involved.  If it was instinctive, than "clever" is not a good way to describe it.

Comment: A better word is *intuitively*. However, if the intuition is complex, as animal behaviour often is, most people find it uncomfortable to believe that a large part of this behaviour (if not all) is inherent. This is why *clever* is more palatable, though wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is perfectly possible. According to the *OED*, the adjective **‘clever’** is more directly related to skill than it is to intelligence. Not too long ago, it was more commonly applied to animals (particularly to horses) than to men. In my opinion *The New York Times* is not using **clever** in its most commonly used sense in present-day English; however, I'd say the sentence is correct.
Check these out:

> A.I.2. Deft or nimble of hands, neat-handed, ‘handy’; adroit, dexterous, or skilful in the use of the limbs and in bodily movements generally.
>
> A.I.3.a. Of persons: Possessing skill or talent; able to use hand or brain readily and effectively; dexterous, skilful; adroit. (The current sense.)

Answer (score 2):

*[Cleverly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cleverly)*

> adverb
>
> In an intelligent, original, or skillful way:

It is true that most *clever* arrangements are purposeful, but the definition provides for the unique instinctive intelligence and skill of a dog. After all, we are not sure that dogs share the same kind (or level) of intentional intelligence. By using my dogs *clever* instincts in training her to do things that are contrary to her other instincts--like sitting quietly while the grandchildren tug on her ears--I have merely demonstrated that I am **more** *clever* than she is.

Comment: I don't feel entirely comfortable describing intelligence of any sort as "instinctive", nor instincts as "clever"; I don't remember seeing those two sorts of descriptions ever used together.

Comment: May I suggest your discomfort is rooted in misunderstanding the meaning of [instinct](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/instinct), [intelligence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intelligence), and [clever](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240999/is-it-possible-to-do-something-both-cleverly-and-unknowingly-at-same-time/241003?noredirect=1#comment520265_241003)?

Comment: From the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=instinctive+intelligence%2C+clever+instinct&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinstinctive%20intelligence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclever%20instinct%3B%2Cc0): [Clever instinct](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22clever%20instinct%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl&safe=active&ssui=on) and [instinctive intelligence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22instinctive%20intelligence%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl&safe=active&ssui=on)

Comment: I notice that all of the first-page references for "clever instinct" refer to human beings; "instinctive intelligence" is a new one on me, but does indeed seem to be used of animals. Your link to the definition of "intelligence", however, refers to "knowledge and skills"; I've never considered animals as having "knowledge" in a philosophical sense.

Answer (score 1):

`Cleverly` simply describes how something was done, and doesn't presume any predisposed knowledge of a given subject, though admittedly it can generally be considered probable. If you were handed a gun and told to dismantle it you could do so cleverly in the way that you didn't start quickly pulling on random things and end up shooting yourself in the foot. Think of it in the same vein as performing a task to the best of your current capability based on your circumstance and level of experience.